# VBA for loop with VLookups avoiding duplicates

Tags: vba, excel

I am compiling a list of employees CPD classes and the hours they are, producing a printout essentially for each one. I am pulling data from multiple worksheets and am having trouble with VLOOKUP continually finding the same data. My code currently is:

```
    result = lookup.Find(name) Is Nothing

    If (result = False) Then
        For Each cell In lookup
            className = Application.VLookup(name, lookup, 7, True)
            classHours = Application.VLookup(name, lookup, 9, True)
            Sheets("employee output").Range("B" & counter).Formula = className
            Sheets("employee output").Range("C" & counter).Formula = classHours
            empHours = empHours + classHours
            counter = counter + 1
            numClasses = numClasses + 1
            corporate = Range("B" & i)  *** vba precompliles the loop so this doesn't work *
            Set lookup = Range("corporate:K") ** doesn't work either***
        Next
        End If
```

So I need to limit the scope of the lookup range or somehow avoid finding the same data. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Change the true to false in your lookups. It will then find an exact match.

Comment: it still finds the same data over and over again. that's what I need to avoid..

Comment: After you find `name` in `lookup`, find the position of this `name` in `lookup`'s first column and offset `lookup` by this value (you can also resize `lookup` so it will always end at the same cell).

Comment: I hope I understood your intentions, but... Now I see that you loop over each cell in `lookup` and I don't understand why.

Comment: perhaps an `.AutoFilter` on the employee would assist you here. If you filter on the employee, you will have a list of their classes / hours / etc. all set up in the `VisibleCells` and you can work with that much easier. Or perhaps even using a `SUMIF(S)` formula can get you what you may need as well. Your code seems a bit clunky for what (it seems) that you are trying to do.

Comment: My code is definitely clunky, I am not a VBA wiz by any means. I think I should just change the loop away from a for each cell loop.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your *lookup* variable represents the range containing you data.

Your data duplication propably comes from your `for each` loop. Indeed, you are iterating trough **each** Cell of your range. That means that once the name is found, the code Inside the loop is executed as many times as there are cells in the range *lookup*.

Try changing your loop to the following:

```
Dim row as Range

for each row In lookup.Row
    'your code goes here
Next
```

Whit this, the code will only run once  for each rows.